# Getting information of currently logged-in user in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I have company page on Facebook, I need to get the userID or username of the user who is currently visiting my page. Is there any way that facebook allows us to get the information of the currently logged-in user?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this on a simple Facebook page. Do you have an application running there?